# CSS Menu add title link

Tags: css

I have this CSS for a vertical menu:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

#vertical_menu {
    float:left;
    padding-left:10px;
}

#vertical_menu > ul > li {
    display:inline-block;
    width:250px;
}
#vertical_menu > li {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    margin-left:-20px;
}
#vertical_menu li a {
    display:block; 
    padding-bottom:10px;
    margin-top:15px;
    border-bottom:4px solid #000000;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
}
#vertical_menu li a:hover { 
    border-color:#666666; 
    color:#666666
}

ul {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

how can i make the `<li>` elements without a a href link different like a menu title so the links below are like a sub menu

here is a fiddle with the full code:http://jsfiddle.net/32hqL/

for example, where it says `Link Title`, needs to be different like a proper title. maybe centered or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can wrap the title in a `span` and then style the span:

```
<li><span>LINK TITLE</span></li>

#vertical_menu li span {}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/32hqL/4/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/32hqL/1/

You do it by using:

```
li:not(a) {
   color: red;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set some style on `#vertical_menu li`, which will be override with `#vertical_menu li a`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/32hqL/3/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/32hqL/11/

CSS

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

#vertical_menu {
    float:left;
    padding-left:10px;
}

#vertical_menu > ul > li {
    display:inline-block;
    width:250px;
}
#vertical_menu > li {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    margin-left:-20px;
}
#vertical_menu li a {
    display:block; 
    padding-bottom:10px;
    margin-top:15px;
    border-bottom:4px solid #000000;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:100;
}
#vertical_menu li a:hover { 
    border-color:#666666; 
    color:#666666
}

ul {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

li:not(a) {
 color: red;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:600;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define set of styles for link title in separate class and give that class to link title li's. Have a look at working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/32hqL/9/

```
.title{
    text-align: center;
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
}
```